# Redhat 5.11 Just showing 1.5TB Storage

Tags: filesystems, rhel, raid5

We purchased new supermicro server with 3*3TB HDDs. Now from Hardware Raid controller i created Raid 5 .So the total use able storage is 5TB something.

But during installation Redhat is just showing 1.5TB instead is 5TB.

I looked for solution but found nothing. Is there a way to solve this issue

Comment: You need to label the array as GPT. IIRC RHEL 5 supports installing on a GPT partition table, but the installer does not support creating the GPT partition table.

Comment: It sounds like you got an actual capacity of 6TB ≈ 5.5TiB, and something is failing to handle >4TiB by passing only the lower 32 bits, leading to a size of ≈1.5TiB.

Comment: sorry guys for late reply. So this is what i did Now im sure that rhel 5 installer doesn't like GPT type. I converted hdd partition type to GPT of sda,sdb and sdc. And tried to reinstall OS . And this time it was showing  hdd with full space. But it started throwing error that boot partition doesn't support GPT.

Answer (score 0):

An MBR formatted drive is limited to 2 TB, you are likely formatting with MBR and getting 1.5 TB of usable space off of that.

For more information on MBR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

You need to format with GPT to use all of the available space on each drive.

For more information on GPT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The MBR partition table limit is 2³² sectors, given 512 bytes (logical) sectors, that's 2TiB. You lose maybe 2MiB of usable space to partitioning—nowhere near 500GiB. There isn't a powers-of-ten vs. powers-of-two thing here, and even if there were that'd be 1.8TiB.